# Visual Studio remote Debugging, choose custom gdb.exe (linux makefile project)

Tags: linux, visual-studio, gdb, remote-debugging

I've got Visual Studio 2017 (Linux and IOT extension installed) and a linux makefile project. The code is compiled using an arm cross-compiler.

When I try to debug, visual studio will always choose one of the gdb.exe in `Common7/IDE/VC/Linux/bin/gdb/8.1`. The decision is made based on the choosen architecture (x86, x64, ARM, ARM64) of the VS project.

However my cross-compiler and the gdbserver running on my device are not compatible with the provided `aarch64-linux-gnu-gdb.exe`.

Is there a way to tell VS to use a specific gdb.exe on my pc?

Replacing files within the VS installation is not an option.

Within `Common7/IDE/VC/VCTargets/Application Type/Linux/1.0/Linux.props` I've found the `GDBRoot` property pointing towards the first directoy, but I failed to override this property.
I prefer to keep a solution instead of a project with the`launch.vs.json` if possible.